# Unable to locate package libpthread-stubs0

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

i am trying to install Oracle 11g in ubuntu 16.04 but while executing the following instructions

```
sudo apt-get install alien autoconf automake autotools-dev binutils doxygen elfutils expat gawk gcc gcc-multilib g++-multilib libstdc++6:i386 ksh less libtiff5 libtiff5-dev lib32z1 libaio1 libaio-dev libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 libc6-i386 libelf-dev libltdl-dev libmotif4 libodbcinstq4-1 libodbcinstq4-1:i386 libpthread-stubs0 libpth-dev libstdc++5 lsb-cxx make pdksh openssh-server rlwrap rpm sysstat unixodbc unixodbc-dev x11-utils zlibc libglapi-mesa:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libpthread-workqueue0 libpthread-workqueue-dev libzthread-2.3-2 libzthread-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev
```

it throws an error message:

```
Unable to locate package libpthread-stubs0
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: ubuntu  16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? It seems Ubuntu is not a supported distribution for Oracle 11g

Comment: i am following tutorial mentioned at this link... http://tutorialforlinux.com/2016/03/28/how-to-install-oracle-11g-r2-database-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-lts-64bit-easy-guide-installing-packages/

Comment: Check my answer. There is no such package in 16.04. If you really need those, install Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial writer in the link you provided was giving incomplete info. there. There is [no `libpthread-stubs0` package in Xenial](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpthread-stubs0&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) official repository. You can't install it in Xenial.

Furthermore, Ubuntu is not a well supported distribution for Oracle. If you really need to install, use Precise (12.04). The package is [available in Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=libpthread-stubs0) repository.

Also check [this forum link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3746197) where it is mentioned that Ubuntu is not a supported platform.

Answer (score 0):

This advice is not useful. Are you sure, that after installation so old Ubuntu will installation work? Another thing is, who want to install so old system for one missing library.